# How to get raw BSON from MongoDB with PHP "mongodb" extension

Tags: php, mongodb, bson

I am trying to get a binary BSON string from mongodb using PHP but I can't figure out how to get the document as BSON. It always parses it to a PHP object first.

I've tried to set a `typeMap` on the cursor but all this does is pass the already parsed PHP object to a `bsonSerialize($object)` function in the class.

The code looks like this:

```
<?php

$db = new \MongoDB\Driver\Manager('mongodb://localhost/test');
$query = new \MongoDB\Driver\Query([]);
$cursor = $db->executeQuery("test.contacts", $query);

foreach($cursor as $document) {
    // $document is already parsed to a PHP stdObject
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In recent MongoDB versions (since 3.6) the documents are returned as part of the responses, and the entire response is serialized as BSON. Meaning, the driver, when it receives a response, has to BSON-deserialize the entire response, and then part of the response will be given to the application as a found document.

There isn't a moment when the driver has just the document alone serialized as BSON.

So, if you need to have an individual document serialized as BSON, you'd need to do that yourself.

Comment: That makes sense, I would accept the entire response serialized as BSON but it seems the PHP driver will always return an `MongoDB\Driver\Cursor` object and there is no way to get the raw response?

Comment: What do you intend to do with the raw response?

Comment: pass it directly into `MongoDB\BSON\toJSON` to see if this has performance gains over a few 1000 documents. by skipping a (what looks like) internal `MongoDB\BSON\toPHP` conversion first.

Comment: OK, supposing you do that, what do you intend to do with json-serialized raw response later?

Comment: I send it to the browser over HTTP and deserialize it with javascript

Comment: You are moving the driver's work (parsing of server response and extracting documents from it) to the frontend. You could do this in principle but essentially you'd be hacking a very limited version of the driver. Just use the driver on the backend.

Comment: Thank you @Oleg, The goal was to do 1 conversion less e.g. `BSON -> JSON` and not `BSON -> stdObject -> JSON`. I think the PHP Cursor object misses a `toJSON()` method for this purpose.

Comment: It doesn't for the reason I described.

Comment: The PHP driver is based on `libmongoc` just like the C++ driver. However the C++ driver is iterating over BSON objects. I've read the BSON spec and every BSON document start with an int32 (size in bytes) I don't see why a driver can't iterate without serialize the entire response first. Fact remains the PHP driver doesn't work this way. If you could reform your answer I'd be happy to accept.

Comment: Server response != an individual document in query result set. You seem to think that the driver deserializes individual documents - it does not.

Comment: No. I think the driver could iterate individual documents without deserialising. I know the PHP driver doesn't work like this but the C++ driver does.